# Is there a way to have a textarea cell with scroll bars?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am trying Tabulator for the first time. One of my field is a multiple line text. I do not want the row to be very tall. I would like the cell to be of limited height but with a vertical scroll bar for that cell. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

The ***textarea*** formatter is just like any other, you can create your own or update it in any way you like, in this case you will want to have a custom formatter that adds a max height to the cell and an overflow auto, you can then assign it to the column definition for the column in question:

```
//multiline text area
var customTextareaFormatter = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
    var el = cell.getElement();
    el.style.whiteSpace = "pre-wrap";
    el.style.overflow = "auto";
    el.style.maxHeight = "50px";
    return this.emptyToSpace(this.sanitizeHTML(cell.getValue()));
};

//assign to column definition
{title:"Description", field:"desc", formatter:customTextareaFormatter},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Oli. It works now. I was wondering if I can define the maximum height in rows as opposed to pixels?

Comment: Great to hear! Im afraid you cant do that, but if you know the font size in the table that should be easy to work out

Comment: Hi Oli. I get the error: Ajax Load Error - Invalid JSON returned SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4

Comment: However I copy and paste the json output into the table using the "data" attribute rather than the "ajaxURL" and it works fine. Any idea?

Comment: that error suggests that the first character returned by the server is a "<" which looks like you are returning HTML rather than a json string as that is probably the start of a tag

Answer (score -1):

If your cell has a `class` or `id`attribute, it should be possible.

Then you can change the css style. You need a fix height and a overflow-y property.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('tabulator-row')[0].style.height = "100px";
document.getElementsByClassName('tabulator-row')[0].style.overflowY = "scroll";
```

If you have no unique id or class for the target element, you can use `querySelector` to select a specific item.

In this example it would select the cell with the attribute `tabulator-field` and the value `name`

```js
document.querySelector('[tabulator-field=name]').style.height = "100px";
document.querySelector('[tabulator-field=name]').style.overflowY= "scroll";
```

Maybe you can use CSS directly. This would be the best solution.

Comment: Is there a way to do so for the tabulator plugin via the formatter?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't use this approach with Tabulator. Because it uses a virtual DOM it is not safe to manipulate any of the cells outside of a formatted as they could be destroyed and rebuilt without notice

Comment: Thanks Oli. Understood! Things are working now but I have one issue: I would like to be able to horizontally scroll the table without the need to first scroll down the page to see the horizontal scroll of the table. Is there a way to have the page horizontal scroll enabled and do that job or any other way? Thanks.